# What is the flap adjustment angle for delta wing Aircraft for take off?

Tags: delta-wing

What is the flap adjustment angle for delta wing aircraft for take off for
the Concorde and the SR-71 Blackbird, given that it has no horizontal stabilisers and that it used elevons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concorde did not have any flaps or slats [as mentioned here](http://www.concordesst.com/wing.html). This is due the fact that they don't have any tails, and wing trailing edge devices do the elevator and aileron jobs and they are called elevons.

Comment: in essence only slats are adjusted